# MongoDB not deleting rows, no error using c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a bit of a strange issue at the moment. I have a chat room style scenario where a "room" is created then each room has "entries" for the chat.

Now I have a web service which can delete rooms, and it will remove the "room" via its id, then it will remove any "entries" which have the same "room-id".

So an example of the schema would be something like:

```
public class Room
{
    Guid Id {get;set;}
    Guid CreatorId {get;set;}
    DateTime DateCreated {get;set;}
}

public class Entry
{
    Guid Id {get;set;}
    Guid RoomId {get;set;}
    string Content {get;set;}
    DateTime DateCreated {get;set;}
}
```

In the above scenario it successfully deletes the room however it fails to delete all entries for that room, but there is no error returned from the query.

The query is basically:

```
var roomQuery = New QueryDocument(new BsonElement("Id", currentRoomId));
var roomResult = roomsCollection.Remove(roomQuery );
if(roomResult .Ok == false)
{ throw new Exception(roomResult .Message); }

var entriesQuery = New QueryDocument(new BsonElement("RoomId", currentRoomId));
var entriesResult = entriesCollection.Remove(entriesQuery );
if(entriesResult .Ok == false)
{ throw new Exception(entriesResult .Message); }
```

currentRoomId is already in context when this is called as it is used to delete the room which is removed successfully without error. However when the entriesCollection is called it returns with an OK of true and no error, but the records are not deleted... is there any gotchas around this stuff that I am missing?

In my scenario there are 2 entries to be deleted and 1 room. As mentioned the room is deleted, the 2 entries are not.

== Edit ==

After searching in the DB via the console here is how the data is being stored:

```
/* 0 */
{
  "_id" : new BinData(3, "/yTE1cDMh0W39IIBueAXdA=="),
  "Id" : new BinData(3, "/yTE1cDMh0W39IIBueAXdA=="),
  "RoomId" : new BinData(3, "xnDcYz2A5kyT5CdYRMSmig=="),
  "Content" : "Some Test Content",
  "DateCreated" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z")
}
```

After trying to do a find like:

```
db.entry.find({ "RoomId" : "63dc70c6-803d-4ce6-93e4-275844c4a68a" }).limit(50);
```

I get 0 matches, and am a little baffled as to why... is it down to the way Mongo is storing the fields so it will be trying to do a text match and failing rather than a binary match or value match etc?

If I was to do:

```
db.entry.find({ "RoomId" : CSUUID("63dc70c6-803d-4ce6-93e4-275844c4a68a") }).limit(50);
```

I get matches, however I don't know how I can infer this type in .net

Comment: I normally use the generic types for building a query. Is the `RoomId` value in MongoDb the same type as you pass in to the query?

Comment: I am using the ClassMap AutoMap functionality on the models above, so it is same type and same name, in MongoVue I can see the rows and have the same name and value as the Room does.

Comment: You're using `QueryDocument` and `BsonElement` though, rather than the strongly typed versions (like `Query<Entry>`), so how is the AutoMap functionality being taken into account?

Comment: Ah yes interesting point, the actual scenario is a little more complicated, as I have a generic repository style pattern which deals with different versions. So in some cases it uses the strongly typed queries and in others where it knows regardless of the version it will always have some bare minimum fields it will use the Bson style query. However once distilled down its pretty much the code above. You do raise a good point, the class maps may not be used in this instance, HOWEVER! I use the same Bson style query to remove the "room", which works fine. So its the same style query in both

Comment: Add the code for the removal of the `Room` to your question.

Comment: I have tried using the Query<T> syntax for this specific instance just to prove/disprove if that was an issue... same result, the 2 entries are not deleted when using: `var query = Query<Entry>.EQ(e => e.RoomId, currentRoomId)`

Comment: from the console, can you `find({'RoomId': ##TheGUID##})

Comment: After trying that have updated the question with an example of the stored data

Comment: Have you considered not storing them as binary? (instead add the BsonRepresentation attribute: `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)] public Guid RoomId { get; set;}`)

Comment: Cannot do that, it would create a dependency on that project to MongoDB, which in this example may seem trivial but in the actual real world application would be bad. Would I be able to do the same sort of inferring at the ClassMap level? as that happens within the top level application, as everything under there is just a POCO and has no knowledge of DB concerns. Or taking the other approach is there a way in the query to tell the query to cast the Guid as a CSUUID or whatever type Mongo uses to compare...

Comment: Haven't tried it, ClassMap should be fine too, as long as API knows your code is using the `Entry` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was causing this eventually!

Like all good issues, this one was caused by me, as my dependency injection configuration was all set up correctly, and was pointing to the correct collection, however in the test rather than pointing to the "Entries" collection it was pointing to "Entry".

It didn't click, even when I was using the GUI to check the table values, and the queries being sent seemed fine.

Anyway there is no issues around searching using GUIDs etc, it was a red herring, so at least the problem is now solved, I hope this helps anyone else who is being an idiot like myself :)